# CSS Hack for IE or Something Else?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following CSS rule:

```
.myClass {
    display: inline-block;
    *
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: left;
    *
    background-color: #ccc;
    *
    border: 0;
    border-bottom-color: #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    *
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

I realize that the asterisk is often used as a hack for certain versions of IE but typically, that usage appears in a different manner as demonstrated here: http://bit.ly/QFRPrQ  All of the responses I have found concerning the use of an asterisk in CSS do not appear to address how it is used in my example.

Is this just the IE hack used in a particular manner or something else?

Comment: i think this just nonsense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's considered a hack for IE because other browsers that render CSS correctly will see that asterisk as a CSS syntax error, and ignore everything after it in the rule.  IE ignores the asterisk and continues rendering the rest of the styles.

I highly recommend avoiding hacks such as this for targeting IE.  Instead, use CSS conditionals designed for targeting IE with specific styling:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Even better might be to use a *feature* detection library instead of trying to target browser specifics. One of the best is http://modernizr.com/